# How to make reusable component in react-native and call them inside other component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a modal component that I want to reuse in future component.

For this reason I want to have it in its own file.

I don't manage to call the component inside the other properly though.

Here is my last attempt of it.

The Modal component code:

```
export const FlyingDescription = (cityDescription) => {
        const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
        return (
                <View>
                        <Modal
                                animation="slide"
                                transparent={true}
                                visible={modalVisible}
                                onRequestClose={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
                        >

                                <View style={styleBoxParent}>
                                        <View style={styleBoxChildren}>
                                                <LinearGradient
                                                        style={styleLinearGradient}
                                                        colors={['#136a8a', '#267871']}
                                                        start={[0, 0.65]}
                                                >
                                                        <Text style={styleText}>{cityDescription}</Text>
                                                        <Pressable
                                                                onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
                                                        >
                                                                <Text style={styleText}>Close</Text>
                                                        </Pressable>
                                                </LinearGradient>
                                        </View>
                                </View>
                        </Modal>
                </View>
        );
};
```

The component where I want to call the Modal component:

```
import FlyingDescription from './FlyingDescription.js';

var utils = require('./utils');


export default class SearchScreen extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.navigation = props.navigation;
                this.state = {
                        searchInput: '',
                        item : {},
                        renderSearch: false,
                        renderFlyingDescription: false,
                };

                this.errorMessage = 'Search for cities...';
        }

        resetState = () => {
                this.setState({
                        item: {},
                        renderable: false,
                });            }

        setSearchInput = (value) => {
                this.setState({
                        searchInput: value
                });
        }

        searchCity = () => {
                this.resetState();
                utils.fetchWeather(this.state.searchInput).then(response => {
                        if (response.cod == 200) {
                                        console.log(response);
                                        this.setItemState(
                                                {
                                                        name: response.name,
                                                        temp: Math.ceil(response.main.temp),
                                                        type: response.weather[0].main,
                                                        desc: 'Humidity: ' + response.main.humidity + '% - ' + response.weather[0].main
                                                }
                                        );
                                        this.setRenderSearch();
                                
}
                });
        }

        setItemState = (newItem) => {
                this.setState(
                                {       
                                        item: newItem,
                                }
                );
        }

        setRenderSearch = () => {
                this.setState(
                                {       
                                        renderSearch: true,
                                }
                );
        }

        render = () => {
                return(
                        <View style={utils.style.container}>
                                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
                                <Text style={utils.style.titleContainer}>☀️  CityWeather</Text>

                                <View style={{alignItems: 'center', width:'90%'}}>
                                        <Text>Search for a city</Text>
                                        <TextInput
                                                onChangeText={(value) => this.setSearchInput(value)}
                                                value={this.searchInput}
                                                style={{ width: '80%', padding: 15, margin: 5, backgroundColor: 'black', color: 'white' }}
                                        />
                                        <TouchableHighlight
                                                style={{backgroundColor: 'grey', padding: 20, borderRadius: 8}}
                                                onPress={this.searchCity}
                                        >       
                                                <Text style={{fontSize: 14, color:'white'}}>Search</Text>
                                        </TouchableHighlight>
                                </View>

                                { this.state.renderSearch ? (
                                        <TouchableHighlight
                                                        underlayColor="white"
                                                        onPress={ () => this.setState({renderFlyingDescription: true})}
                                                >
                                                        <LinearGradient
                                                                colors={['rgba(0,0,0,0.05)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']}
                                                                start={[0, 0.5]}
                                                        >
                                                                <View style={utils.style.row}>
                                                                                                                                                                                         
<Text style={[utils.getTempRange(this.state.item.temp), utils.style.temp]}>
                                                                                        {utils.getEmoji(this.state.item.type)} {this.state.item.temp} °C
                                                                        </Text>
                                                                        <Text style={utils.style.cityName}>{this.state.item.name}</Text>
                                                                </View>
                                                        </LinearGradient>
                                        </TouchableHighlight>
                                        ) : (
// WHERE I WANT TO RENDER MY MODAL COMPONENT
                                                <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', fontSize: 32}}>
                                                        <Text>{this.errorMessage}</Text>
                                                </View>
                                        )
                                }
                                { 
                                        renderFlyingDescription(this.state.renderFlyingDescription, this.state.item.desc)
                                }
                        </View>
                );             
        }
}

export function renderFlyingDescription(isInterpretable, cityDescription) {
        if(isInterpretable) {
                return <FlyingDescription cityDescription={cityDescription} />
        }
}
```

Comment: Try `export default const FlyingDescription ...` or `import {FlyingDescription} from './FlyingDescription.js';` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: Actually my way was working, I had an error because I wasn't managing the cityDescription variable on properly the FlyingDescription side. My question is irrelevant.